# Converting number stored in a VARCHAR field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with payments stored in a column that is of type `VARCHAR`

This is a sample data from the field:

```
10.01
55.11
```

Lately, as part of a new request, we had to remove the decimal point from the number we store in the `VARCHAR` column.

So, I had this:

```
CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(REAL, RTRIM(LTRIM(@amt))) * 100) as PaymentAmount
```

to convert to `REAL` (cannot convert to `BIGINT` from `VARCHAR`), multiply by 100 and then convert to `BIGINT`

Now the issue is, sometimes, during conversion, the end result is 1 cent less.

Example: `'10.11'` gets converted to `1010`, `10.15` to `1014`

Easy way to test this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(REAL, RTRIM(LTRIM(10.15))) * 100) as PaymentAmount
```

The result of the query is `1014`.

I fixed the issue by changing conversion from `REAL` to `FLOAT` and removed conversion to `BIGINT`.

An alternative fix is to use `CAST` like this:

```
CAST(@amt as float)*100  as PaymentAmount
```

I ran conversions with numbers ranging from `10.00` to `10.99` and in that range of 100 values, the **wrong** numbers are:

- `10.11` converts to `1010`
- `10.15` converts to `1014`
- `10.19` converts to `1018`
- `10.23` converts to `1022`

All other values from that range are fine. Curiously, `11.11` converts just fine to `1111`.

So the question is, Why the heck is doing it and whats the pattern? From the [DataType MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx)  REAL is not a precise number, but so is FLOAT and yet float works for the whole range.

EDIT: I failed to mention the `varchar` is of size 1000.

Comment: If you know that `real` isn't a precise number, why not use `decimal` instead?

Comment: You should convert to an exact data type, try `DECIMAL(16,2)` instead of `FLOAT` or `REAL`

Comment: "we had to remove the decimal point from the number we store in the VARCHAR field."  So what's the data currently look like?  The sample data contains a decimal, but this statement indicates that you removed the decimal point.

Comment: never uyse real or float ever for anything that requires you to have correct information.  Why on earth are you storing numbers that you want to use as numbers in a varchar field to begin with? Fix your database design. Eventually you will have a non-number creep in and everything will break. PLus you are making teh server do way more work than is needed and that willeventuially lead to performance issues.

Comment: @Michael Fredrickson: Removing decimal for an output report file, the DB data remains unchanged.

Comment: The formatting of how the data "looks" is a job for the presentation layer. Use money. This ensures that other applications, reports, ETL jobs, etc don't have to decrypt your' custom format for money.

Comment: @brian the DB is the backbone of a big organization and is being used as a standard across multiple projects. I have no clue why they have payment amount stored as a varchar and not money, but there is absolutely no way I can change the datatype or the structure of the standard component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the conversion discrepancies, because like you said, `REAL` is not a precise number...

You're likely seeing a difference between `REAL` and `FLOAT` because each type has a different *mantissa*, which will result in varying loss in precision.  I'm sure you could find a different number which would result in a similar loss of precision while using `FLOAT`.

If you want to understand more of the inner workings of these floating point types, take a look at [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

But in addition to the conversion discrepancies, there's a lot that's off with your solution...

If these are payments... why are you storing the amount in `VARCHAR` field, without the decimal point?  This introduces the possibility for a lot of integrity issues with this data.

Next, wouldn't the [`MONEY` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx) be a more appropriate data type to store... you know... money?

Next, why can't you convert directly from `VARCHAR` to `BIGINT`?  [This is a perfectly valid conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
DECLARE @amt VARCHAR(50)
SET @amt = ' 1001'
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, @amt*100) as PaymentAmount
```

Comment: Cannot convert varchar(1000) to BIGINT. I updated my question with that information.

Comment: MONEY looks a more elegant solution. I looked at money before, I don't know why I didn't go with it in the first place. Perhaps because the SQL output for money did not 'look' right (it had decimals). But the app that reads the data reads the value and outputs it properly without decimals. that was the requirement, to produce an output with no decimals.

Comment: @George I'm still able to cast `varchar(1000)` to `bigint`... assuming that the length of the string in the `varchar` will fit into the `bigint`... but that would be a problem for any numeric data type...

Comment: that is weird, I am getting `Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 6
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.` error when I try to do `SELECT (CONVERT(BIGINT,@amt))*100`

Comment: @George you have to remove the `.` before you convert. `bigint` does not handle decimals.

Comment: @George I'd give Mikael the green check... I was wrong about the state of the data (I thought that the decimal had been removed from the source table).

Comment: @Michael the question was "Why the heck is doing it ... " so I think the check should stay with your answer. My was only workaround that no one asked for :). +1.

Comment: @Michael Its hard to decide who to check when more then 1 answer is good. I gave you the check because you were the only one to suggest using `MONEY` instead of `REAL`. While replacing period works too, I believe converting the value to `MONEY` is the most elegant solution for my problem along with an explanation about approximate numerics.

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @amt varchar(1000)
set @amt = '10.15'

select cast(replace(@amt, '.', '') as bigint)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/2217)